# Keyboard shortcut to comment several lines of code in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

I already made an investigation about the topic, and actually, you can find the answer in the official documentation of JetBrains or just going to **File -> Settings -> Keymap**. However, I can't implement that solution, which is **CTRL + SHIFT + /**.

I don't have a "/" key in my keyboard, but the combination of the number **7** and **SHITF** makes the "/" key, so what I do is to press **CTRL + SHIFT + 7** trying to comment an entire block of code but nothing happens. Doesn't matter if I select English or Spanish in the Prefered Languages panel of Windows, I cannot comment several lines at the same time using that combination.

I know probably I am doing something very very dumb, but honestly, I have been stuck like 20 minutes trying to figure out what I am doing wrong and I am starting to lose any hope.

Sorry for making a dumb question dear folks, but I would really appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: What kind of computer is it that doesn't have `/`? I would enable touch keyboard in the Taskbar.

Comment: @Omid.N Thanks, but I am looking more a quick shortcut to use while I code, just to make things a little bit faster. Also, as you say maybe my computer has the "/" key, but since my keyboard is actually originally made for the Spanish language, I cannot see the key and I would swear I already checked every existent key. Normally I use SHIFT + 7 to make "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add any keyboard shortcut that works on your system in Settings | Keymap:

[image: comment]